# How can I use batch commands to set the permissions of a directory to allow domain users full access

Tags: batch-file, file-permissions

Basically, I have a directory that domain users need to have full access to. They use a batch file to open the piece of software that they use for their work, and this piece of software needs full access to this directory on their C Drive.

I want to add commands to the batch file to make sure this is always the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `cacls` like this:

```
cacls directory /g users:F
```

You will probably need to run this as admin though for it to work though. Unless your domain users have admin rights then you will need to look at another way of going about it.